# Show $P(T < t) =(1-e^{-2\alpha t})^{2}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A system consists of four components that are similar and work independently, say $A,B,C,D$. To operate properly, it is necessary that $(A$ and $B)$ or $(C$ and $D)$ are functioning properly.

Define $T$ as the failure time of the complete system, and $T_{k}$ as the failure time of component $k \in \{A,B,C,D\}$, and suppose that $T_{k}$ ~ $\exp{(\alpha)}$.

Show that $P(T < t) =(1-e^{-2\alpha t})^{2}$

My ideas:

Since we have been given the distribution of $T_{k}'$s, we will have to write $T$ in terms of $T_{A},T_{B},T_{C},T_{D}$

From @antkam's idea, I've got to the following:

Assuming there are only $T_{A},T_{B}$, it follows $T=\min{T_{A},T_{B}}$

$P(T< t)=P(\min{T_{A},T_{B}}<t)=1-P(\min{T_{A},T_{B}}\geq t)=1-P(T_{A}\geq t,T_{B}\geq t)=1-P(T_{A}\geq t)^{2}=1-(\exp(-\alpha t))^{2}=1-\exp(-2\alpha t)$

Comment: Hint: consider just the (A and B) part of the system.  This fails at time $\min(T_A, T_B)$, i.e. the minimum of two exponetial random variables.  Do you know how to calculate that?  If not, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables

Comment: Why does it suffice to consider only $A$ and $B$ part of the system?

Comment: it does not suffice.  i'm just saying as a _subproblem_, consider a system without C or D, i.e., the entire system S is (A and B), and let $T_S$ be the failure time of S = (A and B).  What is the distribution of $T_S = \min(T_A, T_B)$?

Comment: @antkam Since we are using $\min$, we assume a failure can only occur once for $A$ and $B$ respectively, correct? How do I go on to the case with $A, B, C, D$?

Comment: we're not assuming there is only one failure among A and B, but rather, after one of them fails the other doesnt matter.  so first, you find out the failure distribution of (A and B).  then the same for (C and D). then $P(T < t)$ is simply the prob that the whole system has failed, i.e. BOTH subsystems have failed, by time $t$.

Comment: @antkam I am troubled by your use of $\min{(T_{A},T_{B})}$ when we only have two components $A$ and $B$ that are parallel to one another. Say $A$ fails from $t=3$ to $t=6$ and $B$ fails from $t=5$ to $t=8$. $\min{T_{A},T_{B}}=3$ but $T$ will only fail from $t = 5$ to $t=6$, so $T=1$. What am I not understandng correctly?

Comment: oh, you have multiple misunderstandings then... first, when a component fails, it does NOT recover.  it remains failed for all time afterwards.  so e.g. if A fails at $t=3$, it remains failed for all $t \ge 3$.  the exponential $exp(\alpha)$ describes that one moment when A starts to fail.  second, if A fails $t \ge 3$ and B fails $t \ge 5$, then the (A and B) system has failed at time $t \ge 3$ because it requires both A and B to function.

Comment: so lets solve the subsystem E = (A and B) first.  we have $T_E = \min (T_A, T_B)$ because whichever of A/B fails earlier, that's when E fails.  (and remember, nobody ever recovers.)  now $T_A, T_B$ are both exponential $exp(\alpha)$.  look into my earlier wiki link to find the distribution of $T_E$.  can you answer the question: what is $P(T_E < t)$?

Comment: @antkam I noted above $P(T_{E}<t)=1-\exp(-2\alpha t)$

Comment: so you're almost done...  F = (C and D) has the same $P(T_F < t) = 1 - exp(-2\alpha t)$.  Now back to the whole system of (E or F), what is $P(T < t)$?

Comment: I assume it would be $P(T< t)=P(\max{(T_{E},T_{F})}<t)=P(T_{E}<t)^2=(1-\exp(-2\alpha t))^{2}$

Comment: yep, since the whole system only needs E or F to work, the whole system has failed before time $t$ iff both E and F have failed before time $t$.  so you're done.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think my confusion simply stemmed from the fact that $T$ shows time at which the system fails rather than time duration of the system failure